# Python web app - Having N workers doesn't multiply the QPS by N?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-applications, wsgi, gunicorn

I have a synchronous, single process web app with a CPU bound of 2,200 QPS. When I make it multi-processed, the QPS only shows limited increases:

- single process: 2200 QPS. `top` shows CPU at 100%
- 2 workers: 2230 QPS. `top` shows each process at 60%
- 4 workers: 2280 QPS. `top` shows each process at 30%

I don't understand these numbers. Why don't two processes multiply the QPS by 2? Four processes by 4?

### Implementation details

- the web app is just replying to a GET request. I used `Falcon`, it's a copy paste of this [example from the documentation](http://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#learning-by-example)
- the server is running behind `gunicorn`. Here are the command lines for:

  - single-process: `gunicorn things:app`
  - two workers: `gunicorn things:app -w 2`
  - four workers: `gunicorn things:app -w 4`
- I used [`locust`](http://locust.io/) for performing the load tests and measuring the resulting QPS. Configuration: one master and five slaves. Waiting time between each GET request: 0 ms.
- everything is running on the `localhost`. The test machine has 16 cores, so that each process of the web app and each process of the load test is using its own core.

### Some more results

As dano suggested, I inserted a `time.sleep` in the GET handler. Here are the resulting QPS:

[image: QPS as a function of the number of workers and sleep]

Comment: Threads are not magical time-savers that work perfectly in parallel. Multithreading is more intricate/difficult than it may seem.

Comment: You might see more interesting results if you add a `time.sleep(1)` into your GET handler. `time.sleep` releases the GIL, so many threads can be running that command concurrently. I'd expect much better results with multiple workers vs. just one in that case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you're just at the limits of how quickly `locust` can send queries to your server (or perhaps of gunicorn's ability to distribute the requests to workers). With no network latency, and a server doing almost no work (and thus having a very fast response time), it's possible you can respond almost as quickly as locust can send queries.

The gunicorn docs [strongly recommend running it behind NGINX](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html). Maybe give that a try and see how that affects performance.

Comment: Except that the configuration he is using is not multithreaded. Gunicorn uses separate processes for each worker and so each only has one thread. There is no impediment for requests handled by each to run concurrently.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, you're right. I just read this in the OP's question: "When I make it multi-threaded" (and other uses of "thread") and assumed that's actually what the OP did. Thanks for pointing out our mistake!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my post and replaced "threads" by "processes".

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks I checked the docs, and you're right about `gunicorn` using processes (and not threads). But according to the QPS table, adding workers becomes useful when the QPS is I/O bound (sleep 1 sec), which corresponds to the behaviour of threads. It becomes useless when the QPS is CPU bound (little or no sleep), which corresponds to the behaviour of processes. This is very confusing, I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @usualme I wonder if you're just at the limits of how quickly `locust` can send queries to your server (or perhaps of gunicorn's ability to distribute the requests to workers)? With no network latency and a server doing almost not work (and thus having a very fast response time), it's possible you can respond almost as quickly as they can send queries. Also, the gunicorn docs [strongly recommend running it behind NGINX](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html). Maybe give that a try and see how that affects performance.

Comment: @dano Your intuition was right, `locust` was the bottleneck. I increased the number of `locust` slaves to 10. Now the web app achieves 2,200 QPS with 1 process and `4,200` QPS with 2 processes, as it should be. Everything makes sense now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the actual problem, rather than my initial (wrong) recommendation.